# Is AWS pre-emptive (for HTTP result callbacks)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, callback, preemption

I know zero of AWS and am asking for a friend who is a novice Node.Js coder and getting a little out of his depth.

He sends an HTTP request then calls a function which will take some time to execute.

If the HTTP response arrives while the long function is still executing:

- is the function interrupted and the HTTP call-back invoked?
- does the function complete before the callback is executed?
- is there multi-threading so that they run in parallel?

Cooperative, pre-emptive or multithreaded? Which is is it?

Comment: This isn't a question that can be answered in its current form.  Amazon Web Services is a [*"broad set of global compute, storage, database, analytics, application, and deployment services"*](https://aws.amazon.com/pricing/services/) and it isn't clear which of these components you are referring to.  It sort of sounds like you could be talking about the Node.js runtime of AWS Lambda but it is, at least to me, unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will get more info & update the question.